# Рекурсивный обход дерева в глубину на JAVA (postOrder)

Tags: java, рекурсия, бинарное-дерево

У меня есть файл `relations.json`, в котором отражена структура `{id, node, parent, level}`, где:

- node - номер элемента
- parent - номер элемента родительского узла
- level - уровень отношения родительского узла к дочернему

Проблема: я прочитал достаточно много источников на обход дерева в глубину и везде приводятся примеры с `node.left` и `node.right`, то есть везде подразумевается, что у родителя всегда максимум 2-а дочерних узла. Такой вариант мне крайне не подходит потому, что у меня число дочерних нод для каждого узла может варьироваться. Я же застрял в попытках описать внутри рекурсии создание новых дочерних элементов.

Вопрос: как написать рекурсивный метод, в котором можно создавать новые дочерние объекты?

Код:

```
package Tree;

import com.google.gson.Gson;
import POJO.Relations;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;

class Node
{
long id;
long node;
long parent;
long level;

Node left, right;
Node child;

public Node(long id, long node, long parent, long level) {
    this.id = id;
    this.node = node;
    this.parent = parent;
    this.level = level;
    left = right = null;
}
}

class BinaryTree
{
    // Root of Binary Tree
Node root;

BinaryTree()
{
    root = null;
}

void printPostorder(Node node)
{
    if (node == null)
        return;

    // first recur on left subtree
    printPostorder(node.left);
    // then recur on right subtree
    printPostorder(node.right);

    printPostorder(node.child);

    // now deal with the node
    System.out.print(node.id + " ");
}

void printPostorder()  {     printPostorder(root);  }

public static void main(String[] args) {
    BinaryTree tree = new BinaryTree();
    tree.root = new Node(0, 0, 0, 0);
    tree.root.left = new Node(1, 1, 71, 1);
    tree.root.right = new Node(80, 12, 71, 1);

    Gson gson = new Gson();
    BufferedReader br_relations = null;
    try {
        br_relations = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("files/relations.json"));
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    Relations[] relations = gson.fromJson(br_relations, Relations[].class);
    for (Relations r : relations) {
        tree.root.child = new Node(r.getId(),r.getNode(),r.getParent(),r.getLevel());
    }

    System.out.println("\nPostorder traversal of binary tree is ");
    tree.printPostorder();
    }
}
```

Comment: Что у вас уже получилось? Добавте код прямов вопрос.